# Is Multi-label Weighted Training in TFLearn Possible

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tflearn

[Link to TFLearn doc on Image PreLoader](http://tflearn.org/data_utils/#image-preloader)

Specifically is there a folder structure or file format (preferably) that allows for specifying a 'percentage' of a class the training image contains? The input format should be a class and a weight between 0 and 1.

I am using the standard file setup as outlined in the TFLearn documentation:

```
path/to/file1 1
path/to/file2 1
path/to/file3 2
...
```

Where the numbers on the right specify the class of the file on the left.

The problem with this is, say you have a picture of a dog and a cat, you can't specify dog AND cat, only dog or cat. Further, it would be ideal to specify something like 50% cat, 50% dog.

This is what I would like:

```
path/to/file1 1 0.70 2 0.25 3 0.05
path/to/file2 1 1.
path/to/file3 2 0.5 3 0.5
...
```

Where the classes are defined by their 'prominence' in the input.

Comment: Can you show your attempts so far? Also, what have you been using for non-weighted training? Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: I've been using the standard setup as specified in the docs. I'll add it to the description.